# Decimal to Binary based on the logic B[i]*(2)^i Where i=[0,2,3...N-1]

Tags: algorithm, binary, decimal

I have a function that takes a binary array and returns a decimal based on the below logic:

```
1  |  -2  |  4  |  -8  |  16  |  -32 ...
1  |  0   |  0  |  1   |  1   |  1   = 1 + 0 + 0 + (-8) + 16 + (-32) = -23
```

```
def bin_to_dec(bin_array):
    dec = 0
    for i in range(0, len(bin_array)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            dec += bin_array[i] * 2**i
        else:
            dec += bin_array[i] * -2**i
    print(dec)
    return dec
```

I am struggling with writing the decimal to binary piece of the above logic. As in a function that takes for example -23 as input, and returns [1,0,0,1,1,1]. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is often called [negabinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#Calculation), or more generally 'negative base notation'

Comment: Seems like the title has a few typos: it should probably be B[i]*(-2)^i with i in [0,1,2,3...N-1]

Comment: Any issues with the provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few observations to solve this:

1. Consider a 5-bit number with the coefficient of `16` as `1`. What could be the maximum value of the number? `21 = 1 + 4 + 16`. Similarly, minimum value would be `6 = 16 - 2 - 8`. So, for any number between `[6,21]`, the coefficient of `16` is guaranteed to be `1`.
2. Similarly, for a 6 bit number, if `-32`'s bit is `1`, the range of numbers will be between `[-42, 11]` `-32 - 2 - 8 = -42` and `-32 + 16 + 4 + 1 = 11`
3. Now, each number `x` can be expressed in two ways for our problem:
   a. `(some binary number <= x)` + `(some positive value)` (for example, `20 = 16+4`)
   b. `(some binary number >= x)` + `(some negative value)` (for example, `7 = 16+(-9)`)
4. Combining point #3 and #4, you can determine the most significant bit of the number. Calculate the range for the `biggest binary number <= x` (by binary number, I mean exponent of `2`). If `x` is outside the upper limit of the range, we'll use method `3b` to express it as a sum, or else method `3a`.
   Example: for `20`, biggest exponent = `16` which has range `[6,21]`, so we'll use `3a`. However, for `30`, we'll have to use `3b` and express it as `64 + (some negative value)`.
5. Similarly, for negative numbers, you can use the lower bound of range to see which will be the biggest negative exponent. Example: for `-9`, biggest exponent = `-8`, which has range `[-10,-3]`. Since lower bound of `-10` < `-9`, we can express it as `-8 + (some negative value)`. For `-14`, we'll have to express it as `-32 + (some positive value)`

Using all of this, you can come with an implementation (either recursive or iterative, your decision). The algorithm would broadly look like:

```
convert(i):
x = rightmost bit/exponent for i
diff = difference between x and i
return x + convert(diff)
```

Using `-23` as example:

1. `Biggest exponenent <= -23 = -8`. Since it is outside `-8`'s range, we make it `-32 + (9)`. Recursively solve for `9`.
2. `Biggest exponenent <= 9 = 4`. Since it is outside `4`'s range, we make it `16 + (-7)`. Recursively solve for `7`.
3. `Biggest exponenent <= -7 = -2`. Since it is outside `-2`'s range, we make it `-8 + (1)`. Recursively solve for `1`.
4. For `1`, we get `1`.

So we get `(-32)+(16)+(-8)+(1)`, which was the original summation.

Comment: I like this answer, as it seems creative and distinct from the standard way of converting to negabinary. I'm not sure I understand how the pseudocode relates to the rest of your description, since the pseudocode doesn't mention anything about the "ranges" used in the rest of your explanation. This could also use more details about calculating the ranges and rightmost bit/exponent.